# how to display user name in php after logged in?

Tags: php

could anyone help, i'm trying to display the first name of a user after being logged in with no luck, if anyone could help me i would really appreciate it, and please if you are not going to help me dont put a negative on my question or criticize me, it really does not help at all, im new at this so, thanks

this is my code after being logged in:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['loggedIn'] != "true") {
header("Location: login.php");}
?>
<html>
<head>
```

Comment: Are you storing the user's first name in the `$_SESSION` superglobal? If so, can what is the associated key (i.e. `$_SESSION[key]` where key is something like `firstname`)? In addition, just as a heads up, you should add `exit;` right after `header("Location: login.php");` This stops the rest of your script from executing and immediately redirects vs finish executing and then redirecting. It's a little optimization but it has bitten me before.

Comment: `I'm trying to display the first name of a user after being logged in with no luck`. Please include the code you tried and tell us what went wrong.

Comment: If you want to avoid downvotes, start by reading the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), more specifically [How Do I Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: this is not enough code for us to help you.  what's in `$_SESSION`?  What does your PHP code do to try to print out the user's name?

Comment: With your current code the if statement will never be executed because the session will have just been started.

Comment: Also, you must at least make some attempt to accomplish your task before asking us to do it for you.

Comment: @DavidCorbin Not true. You always have to start the session to use session variables within the script. As long as `$_SESSION['loggedIn']` was set on some other page, presumably the login page, this is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on the limited code provided, my best guess would be to assign the user information to the `$_SESSION` variable, or assign the user_id to a `$_SESSION` variable and do a db query if the `$_SESSION['logged_in'] === true` and use the db result to display the user's name or redirect them to the login page.